# How to design a SQL Server table with shared columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to achieve an optimal design merging columns from two SQL Server tables in just one in order to achieve better design and optimization.

Table1 - application for users

```
ApplicationID
FirstName
LastName
Address
```

Table2 - application for partners

```
ApplicationID
CompanyName
Address
TaxID
```

Would it be wise to skip creation of tables 1,2 and create a table 3 that will look like this

```
table3
---------
ApplicationID
FirstName
LastName
CompanyName
Address
TaxID
```

Columns that are not shared between two tables would be left nullable. Is this a good way to design a SQL Server table, or I should stick to two different tables and add a table3 that would hold a master key `ApplicationID`

```
table3
-------
ApplicationID
ApplicationType (client, company)


table1 //application for users
--------
ApplicationID
FirstName
LastName
Address

table2 //application for partners
---------
ApplicationID
CompanyName
Address
TaxID
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the Type of relationship between this Tables.

DO an ERM so you will see, that the best option is to Create 3 Tables.

1. T_USER

   - User_Id (PK)
   - FirstName
   - LastName
   - Adress
2. T_Partners

   - Company_Id (PK)
   - CompanyName
   - Adress
   - TaxId (This could be the PK too)
3. T_Application

   - Company_Id (FK & PK)
   - User_Id (FK & PK)

Comment: You could even move address to its own table. It would make each table smaller and more efficient and it could also handle duplicated address.

Comment: me neither. @Joshua Schwarz may give you more information.

Comment: dont understand table 3. Why use company_ID and user_id as a composite PK?

Comment: You can use Company_ID and User_ID as PK together, so you will never have a one and the same assignment two times.
In this case it is called a complex primary key.

Comment: @JulienVavasseurIn this way you can make valid assignments, a user can get more then one Company_ID and a Company can get more then one User_ID.
One More benefit is, that you dont have one more column, so your Database is smaller.
Additionally you dont have to check if your addignments are claerly and unique.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you skip creation of tables `users` and `partners` and you want to update address for some user (e.g. 'John Smith') in table 3. In this case you will write some UPDATE-query. For example something like this

```
UPDATE table3 SET address='new address' WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Smith'
```

This approach require additional overhead, because if you have a lot of rows in table 3 it will take very long time. Additionally if you have 2 and more users with first name 'John' and last name 'Smith' it will be difficult to distinguish them.

If you create separate table for users it will be pretty simple to manage users information. In this case your tables will be *normalized*. In case when all your data located in one table with a lot of columns you have *denormalized* table. This approach have some advantages, but in most of cases you have to *normalize* your data.

Short answer to your question: 3 tables with a few columns is better (in most cases) than 1 big table with a lot of columns.

Comment: What about UPDATE table3 SET address='new address' WHERE applicationID = 3?? + for normalization

Comment: Same problem - you are trying to update data, that is not belongs to entity from `table 3`. This data (address) belongs to some user, because user has an address (lives on the street), not the entity from `table 3`. When your data is normalized (i.e. table `users` exists) you have to update only one row in table `users`. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say)

Comment: In other words, user _own_ address. That's why column `address` has to be located in the table `users`. I'm sorry for my English, perhabs sometimes I make mistakes)